# Elementwise Multiplication of a Tensor with multiple scalars

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Assume the following input:

```
x = torch.randint(1, 5, size=(2, 3, 3))
print(x.shape)
torch.Size([2, 3, 3])
```

I want to perform an elementwise multiplication with multiple scalars. The scalars are available in this tensor:

```
weights = torch.tensor([2, 2, 2, 1])
print(weights.shape)
torch.Size([4])
```

So, basically, I want 4 operations :

```
result_1 = x * weights[0]
result_2 = x * weights[1]
result_3 = x * weights[2]
result_4 = x * weights[3]
```

packed in one tensor. However, simply doing

```
result = x * weights
```

will not work, since the dimensions are not correct for broadcasting. My current solution is rather ugly and I assume not efficient :

```
x = x.unsqueeze(0).repeat_interleave(4, 0)
result = x * weights[:, None, None, None]
```

I am looking for a better way!

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good! If you want something else, try the `.view()` method. It reshapes the tensors:

```py
x = x.view(1, *x.shape)  # Shape: (1, 2, 3, 3)
weights = weights.view(-1, 1, 1, 1)  # Shape: (4, 1, 1, 1)
```

If you want to use the `.unsqueeze()` method, then maybe you can write it like this, but I still dig yours better (I didn't test this one):

```py
x = x.unsqueeze(0)  # Shape: (1, 2, 3, 3)
weights = weights.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2).unsqueeze(3)  # Shape: (4, 1, 1, 1)
```

Please let me know how it goes!